# nodejs dont recognize own extension instead of JSON

Tags: json, node.js, file

I am trying to use own `.extension` for `.JSON` files. But when I require them node don't recognize them.

For example when I do:

```
var users = require('users.json');
```

users is now a object like:

```
name: 'somebody', age: 27
```

When I do just the same file but other .extension"

```
require('users.myextension')
```

users is now empty;

```
=> {}
```

Is there a way to fix this, otherwise I have to use just JSON as extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [globals](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions)

In short you can instruct how require should load a file in this way:

```
require.extensions['.extension'] = require.extensions['.json'];
```

Please mind that this is deprecated but as stated in the note the feature probably will not be removed since the module system is locked.

Comment: Ok thx, but there must be a future solution for software builders using there own extension?

Comment: Well actually for your use case you are pretty safe including the json file in that way, but if you want a rock-solid solution is to read the file through the fs module and parse it using JSON.parse

Comment: Ok, I want to pass for the fs system cause i think require the file the node way will have performance gains.